# Can not ping my IoT device using IPv6

Tags: networking, server, network-manager, ethernet, dhcp

I am trying to ping6(ping with IPv6) an IoT device from an ubuntu machine. I installed a DHCPv6 server on ubuntu machine and connected both the ubuntu machine and IoT device to the same network. My IoT device could get global inet6 address form the subnet I configured in DHCPv6 server. Ifconfig of my IoT device is something like this.

```
 Iface  10  HWaddr: E2:98:06:85:7D:E1  Channel: 1
           L2-PDU:249  MTU:1280  HL:64  RTR
           RTR_ADV  6LO  Source address length: 6
           Link type: wireless
           inet6 addr: fe80::e098:6ff:fe85:7de1  scope: link  VAL
           inet6 addr: 2002:db6:0:1:e068:6ff:fe55:7de1  scope: global  VAL
           inet6 group: ff02::2
           inet6 group: ff02::1
           inet6 group: ff02::1:ff85:7de1
```

but I could not get any global IPv6 address on my ubuntu machine. It only shows the hardware address. My ifconfig of ubuntu machine looks something like this(change IP address values for security)

```
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
    RX packets 5744  bytes 686072 (686.0 KB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 5744  bytes 686072 (686.0 KB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp1s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 176.128.31.395  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 176.168.31.255
        inet6 fe80::1f2a:8e01:ff47:4c93  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 80:30:49:40:c8:03  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1670569  bytes 2345477288 (2.3 GB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 277495  bytes 27047722 (27.0 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Things I tried

- Change the '/etc/network/interfaces' file by adding inet6 dhcp. My interfaces file look like this.

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d
iface wlp1s0 inet6 dhcp
```

Aftet restart, nothing changed.

- Added manually a sub net to interface

```
ip address add 2002:db6::1/128 dev wlp1s0
```

- Various configurations in file interfaces but lost my wifi completely.

I am new to Networking. I do not understand where I am making wrong. I am sure I need to do some configurations to my ubuntu machine to ping

```
ping6 2002:db6:0:1:e068:6ff:fe55:7de1%wlp1s0
```

Thank you for your help and time.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: I am using ubuntu 20.04